# I always come across a problem of Blender not responding whenever I use hair particles, how can I fix this?

Tags: particles

Whenever I try to use hair particles in blender, blender just freezes and stops responding. This happens every time, with every version of blender I have ever used.

PC:

LENOVO S145 | INTEL CORE i5 | 8GB RAM

Comment: When hair particles get too much, it gets very heavy. And 8GB RAM isn't such a good amount to deal with hair particles unless the scene is very basic.

Comment: I have my CPU and RAM monitor on at all times. My RAM usage doesn't even hit 50%, I even tried using only a sphere in the scene but I got the same results.

Comment: What about your CPU?

Comment: they both remain low, The CPU does not hit 20% mark

Comment: What is the hair count when blender stops responding?

Comment: default settings

Comment: Hmmmm, what version of blender are you using? What about the mesh that you use the hair particles on? Is it too heavy?

Comment: I have used versions from 2.82 to 2.93, they all yield the same results. on a simple mesh as the default sphere

Comment: That's strange. Did you try loading factory settings by going to File>Defaults>Load Factory Settings? Also try resetting your preferences.